# Permission Denied (public key)

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a google cloud instance. I'm able to successfully connect to the instance via ssh.

But I'm not able to do the port forwarding to my localhost.

Here's the command I used:

`ssh -L 16006:127.0.0.1:8080 username@instance_external_ip`

When I run the above command , I get the following error

`The authenticity of the host cannot be determined.
username@instance_external_ip : Permission Denied (public key)`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks to me like you _can't_ connect via SSH.  Have you opened your instance to SSH connections?

Comment: Yes, I have opened it using gcloud

Comment: But I'm not able to port forward it to my localhost. I'm running tensorboard in cloud

Comment: If I cannot connect via ssh, how do I run tensorboard running on cloud localhost in my localhost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer for this question. The problem I had was that the server did not know the ssh keys. So, I did the following and it worked.

I deleted all the ssh keys in the my local machine and connect to my gcloud instance using the following command. gcloud command creates the ssh keys automatically and it transfers to the cloud ssh keys automatically. So, no need to manually copy paste the keys.

`gcloud compute --project "project_name" ssh --zone "zone_name" "instance_name"`

After this I connected to my instance using ssh. Before doing if you try to ssh tunnel , as the server won't be aware of the localhost, it will say permission denied on running `ssh -L ....`.

Therefore, instead of directly connecting through `ssh -L ...` , connect along with `ssh-key` file stored in `.ssh` directory. Use the following command.

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute-engine -L <ur localhost port number>:127.0.0.1:<remote_host_port> username@server_ip`